# Return file using HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

Good afternoon. I need to download data from database in excel format. Below, my code and its working correct when i'm trying to download file through firefox, but using chrome this view returning archive with some `openpyxl` files. `Openpyxl` - this library i'm using to filling excel table from database in `excel_download()` function. Will you please help me to solve it?

```
def excel_download_view(request, **kwargs):
    if 'sorting_argument' in kwargs:
        queryset = Lot.objects.filter(
            Q(bank__slug__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument']) |
            Q(auction_date__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument']) |
            Q(which_time_auction__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument']) |
            Q(fgvfo_number__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument']) |
            Q(prozorro_number__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument']) |
            Q(decision_number__iexact=kwargs['sorting_argument'])
        )
    else:
        queryset = Lot.objects.all()

    excel_download(queryset)

    data = None

    with open('media/excel/lots.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by the [response-as-a-file-attachment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment), try it:

```
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="lots.xlsx"'
return response
```